# Parsing data from filename; variable assignments in loop different from console

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to parse some data from a filename containing certain key words in any order. For example, a filename can be called `paidYes_cashYes_cardNo_billsYes_coinsNo_112916.csv`

I want to assign each parameter (paid, cash, card, bills, coins) yes or no so that I can rebuild the filename using the `strcat` command. In the case of my filename provided the desired variables would look like this:

```
paid = 'paidYes';
cash = 'cashYes';
card = 'cardNo';
bills = 'billsYes';
coins = 'coinsNo';
tail = '112916.csv';
```

So far I have created a script that will save all the variables containing 'Yes', however I'm not getting consistent results when I run the script/debugging mode compared to testing it by hand in the console.

```
>> edit cashname

filename = 'paidYes_cashYes_cardNo_billsYes_coinsYes_112916.csv';
namearray = strsplit(filename,'_'); % Splits string into a 1x6 cell

i = 1;
for n = namearray{i} % 'Yes' containing variables only!
       if strfind(n,'paidYes') > 0
           paid = 'paidYes';
       elseif strfind(n,'cashYes') > 0
           cash = 'cashYes';
       elseif strfind(n,'cardYes') > 0
           card = 'cardYes';
       elseif strfind(n,'billsYes') > 0
           bills = 'billsYes';
       elseif strfind(n,'coinsYes') > 0
           coins = 'coinsYes';
       end
i = i + 1
end
```

When I carry out the script, I find that `n` is assigned the first letter of the string! The results for `n` and `i` are below if they are not suppressed:

```
>> cashname
n = p
i = 2
n = a
i = 3
n = i
i = 4
n = d
i = 5
n = Y
i = 6
n = e
i = 7
n = s
i = 8
```

However, when I enter commands in debug mode or in the console I get the full string being output:

```
>> length(namearray)
     ans = 6
>> i = 2;
>> n = namearray{i}
     n = 
     cashYes
```

Did I find some kind of bug, am I doing something syntactically wrong, and how can I fix this?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of `namearray` contains the delimited data as a `char` array.  When you write,

```
i = 1;
for n = namearray{i}
```

MATLAB interprets it as

```
for n = 'paidYes'
```

and since the "`for` statement overrides any changes made to index within the loop" [[src](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html#moreabout)], the index `n` will run over the elements of that `char` array, which is expected and seen.

The two alternatives I will suggest, in addition to using a `switch` statement for clarity, are iterating over the elements of the `namearray` directly

```
for n = namearray
    switch n{1}
        case 'paidYes'
            paid = 'paidYes';
        case 'cashYes'
            cash = 'cashYes';
        case 'cardYes'
            card = 'cardYes';
        case 'billsYes'
            bills = 'billsYes';
        case 'coinsYes'
            coins = 'coinsYes';
    end
end
```

or use an integer `for`-loop index to access the `namearray` elements

```
for n = 1:length(namearray)
    switch namearray{k}
        case 'paidYes'
            paid = 'paidYes';
        case 'cashYes'
            cash = 'cashYes';
        case 'cardYes'
            card = 'cardYes';
        case 'billsYes'
            bills = 'billsYes';
        case 'coinsYes'
            coins = 'coinsYes';
    end
end
```

Comment: Great response and thank you for introducing me to the 'switch-case" type of flow control that I was not aware of.

In regards, to using `n = namearray` vs `n = 1:length(namearray)` - is there any benefit to using one over the other or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: @PatrickB. On my R2016a install, the `1:length(namearray)` runs far faster than the other way.  So performance is an issue.  However, in the past, I've used the other way for semantic reasons (for example, `for field = fields` reads nicley to me and the performance is dwarfed by the rest of the code).  Semantics versus performance is, to me, a matter of personal choice.